# Nokogiri parsing different on server versus localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

I'm getting some weird differences when running Nokogiri locally versus running it on my server. On my local machine the entire document seems to parse and be available but on the server I seem to get the doctype tab and some random comment tags.

To start off, to make sure it wasn't a problem with open-uri I checked it - the results are not exact but do contain the correct markup.

Local:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :005 > s = open('http://www.pennstateind.com/store/PK2WAY.html')
=> #<File:/var/folders/G8/G8bsAGBk1o82Eyks3ZmFtq-+3Y6/-Tmp-/open-uri20120626-5891-10y2ncr-0> 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :006 > s.length
=> 88408
```

Server:

```
rb(main):008:0> s = open('http://www.pennstateind.com/store/PK2WAY.html')
=> #<File:/tmp/open-uri20120626-22167-1td2l72-0>
irb(main):009:0> s.length
=> 98184
```

When I run this on my local machine I get this:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :003 > d = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.pennstateind.com/store/PK2WAY.html'))
=> [ OUTPUT OMITTED FOR BREVITY - CAN SUPPLY ON REQUEST ] 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :004 > d.to_s.length
=> 85212
```

But when I run this on the server I get this:

```
rb(main):006:0> d = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.pennstateind.com/store/PK2WAY.html'))
=> #<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x36620e14b580 name="document" children=   [#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x36620e14b1c0 name="html">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x36620e14b170 " Open Graph Tags ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x36620e14a98c " Customer_Session_Verified: 0 ">]>
irb(main):007:0> d.to_s.length
=> 172
```

The only apparent gem difference is for the JS compiler - all other gems are the exact version between local and server:

```
Local => libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86-darwin-10)
Server => libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-linux)
```

Any ideas how to figure out what is going on and/or fix this?

---

Update - to isolate where the problem actually was I pulled a file from the server and from localhost then ran them on each. The results below show that the problem definitely lies in Nokogiri - what the problem is I am still perplexed by...

Running locally:

```
# FILE ORIGINALLY PULLED FROM SERVER

ruby-1.8.7-p352 :015 > server_file = File.open("/Users/jmcdonald/Desktop/files/SERVER.txt", "r")
=> #<File:/Users/jmcdonald/Desktop/files/SERVER.txt> 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :016 > server_file.read.length
=> 93071 

ruby-1.8.7-p352 :022 > Nokogiri::HTML(server_file).to_s.length
=> 98793

# FILE ORIGINALLY PULLED FROM LOCALHOST

=> #<File:/Users/jmcdonald/Desktop/files/LOCAL.txt> 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :018 > local_file.read.length
=> 89622

ruby-1.8.7-p352 :026 > Nokogiri::HTML(local_file).to_html.length
=> 94632
```

Running on server:

```
# FILE ORIGINALLY PULLED FROM SERVER

irb(main):001:0> sf = File.open('/home/charlest/public_html/files/nokogiri_issue/SERVER.txt', 'r')
=> #<File:/home/charlest/public_html/files/nokogiri_issue/SERVER.txt>
irb(main):002:0> sf.read.length
=> 93071

irb(main):004:0> Nokogiri::HTML(sf).to_s.length
=> 896      # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< WRONG

# FILE ORIGINALLY PULLED FROM LOCALHOST

irb(main):008:0> lf = File.open('/home/charlest/public_html/files/nokogiri_issue/LOCAL.txt', 'r')
=> #<File:/home/charlest/public_html/files/nokogiri_issue/LOCAL.txt>
irb(main):009:0> lf.read.length
=> 89622

irb(main):011:0> Nokogiri::HTML(lf).to_s.length
=> 896      # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< WRONG
```

Comment: Have you tried using curl or something like that to see if the URL you are hitting is just returning different stuff in different cases?

Comment: Yes - I used open-uri from irb to confirm that the data I'm getting back is valid in both cases. The size appears to be different but that appears to be where white space has been stripped out on the server but not on localhost. The actual markup appears to be the same when I compare them.

Comment: To validate my response I just tried copying the response from open-uri on localhost, saved it to a file on the server, then read it in to Nokogiri. I get the expected result then, which tells me that open-uri is indeed returning something that is different, even if it appeared to be the same on my initial analysis. Going down that path now...

Comment: I tested out a little more and found that the files from open-uri are valid and working correctly. The differences between the files ended up not being spacing but random content that changed on the page each time it was visited. See the updates to my original post above for more information - the problem definitely lies in Nokogiri.

Comment: What are the libxml2 versions on each host? Nokogiri itself is highly unlikely to be the cause of parse differences like this. Guessing your server is using an old libxml2 version.

Comment: I've isolated this to a problem with the instance of the Nokogiri gem. While playing around I noticed that Nokogiri document size was correct whenever I was using the global gems on the server and not my bundled gems. So I blew away all my gems and found that if I do a "gem install" it is wrong, however if I copy the gem that is already installed on the server to my local gems dir and run it again, it is correct. I've filed a ticket with my host to try to get clarification on what they did to install the server version. Will update here when I know more.

Comment: Still waiting to hear back from my host, however in digging deeper the server (CentOS) is definitely running an old version of libxml2 (2.6.26). Have asked host to update this to a more recent version. If they will update I will try again and post results here. My guess is that they set up a machine, installed all the gems, then copied them over to the other machines without updating the dependencies like libxml2, but not entirely sure - just a hunch.

Comment: This is resolved now. My host had an old version of libxml2 (2.6.26) and had done something to get their server level Nokogiri gem working (nobody seems to be sure what had been done to get it to work though). I updated the libxml2 package to use version 2.8.0, updated my Nokogiri gem, and now it works fine.

Comment: @x1a4 - if you want to put your response as an answer I'll mark it as correct and upvote it.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on Nokogiri 2.6.2 as described on this issue https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1383

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your server and local environment are using different versions of [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/). Older versions are known to have strange parsing bugs, so updating your server to the latest version you possibly can (or at least to the same version you're using for development) should fix you up.

Comment: The problem was indeed with an old version of libxml2 being installed on the server. Updated libxml2 to version 2.8.0 and everything works great now.

Answer (score 2):

There was also a bug with a shipped version of Nokogiri (I believe it affected 1.5.1) which affected the parsing in a some limited situations.  I would suggest making sure your gems are updated.  (gem update)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm not having luck regardless of the version. I've tried this test with everything from 1.5.0 to 1.5.5, all with the same results. See my comment above on the server versus local install though - something is definitely going on with the actually install but I'm waiting to hear back from my host on what.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `File#read` rather than `File#open` or make sure you're running `lf.rewind` before you try to parse w/ Nokogiri. The behavior you're seeing is most likely the result of your `lf` file handle being at the end of the file, which means Nokogiri is parsing an empty document.

```
> remote = File.open('./PK2WAY.html')
# => #<File:./PK2WAY.html>
> remote.read.length
# => 92978
> remote.read.length
# => 0
> Nokogiri::HTML(remote).to_s.length
# => 108
> remote.rewind
# => 0
> Nokogiri::HTML(remote).to_s.length
# => 93847
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a valid problem with doing this (so it may help others) but not the problem in my particular case. I simplified the responses to limit the amount of text showing up. The example I pasted isn't in the order I executed - just the order to show what is going on.